# MPAndroidChart - horizontal custom dynamic coordinate highlight

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm using a MPAndroidChart for graphing. My question is related to highlights. There are two types of highlights:

1. vertical highlight
2. horizontal highlight

In my use case I'm satisfied with the behavior of the vertical highlight but I'd like to be able to customize the behavior of horizontal highlight. Now the vertical highlight is set to the middle of the candle body in case of candlestick chart and horizontal is set somewhere else - static.

I'd like to customize the horizontal highlight to be on the position of the finger. So if I put my finger on one of the CandleEntry the horizontal highlight would go up and down by the actual position of my finger (maybe onDrag event).

My question is how to achieve this:

1. is there some built-in method for this behavior
2. or do I have to implement it on my own? If so, then can you give me advice or some hint how to achieve this.

I'd appreciate any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried but it may be done by using limit line. Give it a try !